# How do i debug where windsor resolve containers?

Tags: c#, debugging, castle-windsor

I am in debug inside a constructor initialized by Windsor. I need to find a reference to the windsor container to use the following line of code.

```
container.Resolve<IPerson>(new { id = 5 });
```

But I don't have the variable container. 
The solution has 200 projects and I need to find where the Windsor starts.

Which is the state of the art technique to debug this kind of problem? 
Is there a way to find the source code where the .Resolve operation happens?

---

Just to better clarify what I mean, the solution for other classes of problems is:

- Looking at call stack
- Enabling a different Exception handling from Visual Studio
- Playing with the Just My code option
- writing in the quickwatch Transaction.Current (which is a static class visible everywhere)

Answer (score 1):

Windsor doesn't resolve containers, since you need a container to resolve a service to a component. Usually the container is the composition root, which means that it presides over the creation of all components you may need. Using a container in your code is not a good idea since it ties specific code to the general setup of your application.

You should isntead use the fact that the container can resolve the needed components for you; here are ways to do it:

- Add a `IPerson` parameter to your constructor and let it resolve the `IPerson` for you. If the resolution is static (ie always the same id) you can tell Windsor to resolve a service to a [specific instance](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Register_existing_instance:_5).
- If you cannot resolve the `IPerson` when building the constructor, resolve a `IPersonFactory` in your object. This [factory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) would take an integer and return an IPerson. This way you are still separated from the container but you can load the data you need.
- If you really need to use the container (although you should be able to do without) you can register the `IWindsorContainer` service to the container intance during configuration and add a `IWindsorContainer` parameter to your constructor; the container will be available to your object.

Though it is simple, I really don't recommend the last approach; letting your code know about the container is not really recommended

Answer (score 1):

> I am in debug inside a constructor initialized by Windsor. ... But I
>   don't have the variable container.

That's one the main reasons why IoC containers are used - in order to keep your code clean and be responsible for object creation.

> The solution has 200 projects and I need to find where the Windsor starts.

Windsor starts where its constructor is invoked `new WindsorContainer()` (see [Bootstrapping Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-four-putting-it-all-together.ashx#Bootstrapping_Windsor_1)).

```
container = new WindsorContainer()
    .Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

For MVC web application you'll find these lines of code in `Global.asax.cs`.

> Is there a way to find the source code where the .Resolve operation
>   happens?

e.g. for MVC web application it happens in custom controller factory which is initialised in `Global.asax.cs`

```
var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

There is an [example of custom controller factory implementation](https://github.com/ripper234/Kuzando/blob/7aee50d0611afbe849cf53c8cd9dbfa3b020d4f5/Code/Kuzando.Common/Web/WindsorControllerFactory.cs):

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    private readonly WindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(WindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        return (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerName);
    }

    public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _container.Release(controller);
    }
}
```

So `_container.Resolve(controllerName)` is the place where Resolve method is invoked. Resolving (building, creating) controller container tries to resolve all its dependencies using information about registered types.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get to the Composition Root -> The class/factory/whatever in which the resolution starts.
2. Find the registered factories in the main install class. Probably some class which implements IWindsorInstaller. If your project is that large you will probably have multiple installer classes for the different modules of the application. In the Core Installer you will probably find the factories which Castle uses to create and provide the parts of the whole object graph.
3. Examine it carefully with pen and paper scathing the whole object graph in order to minimize the guess work during debugging and not to fall into "Shotgun debugging" which is exhaustive and at the end you did not learn anything about the system. Find where the parameters for the constructor come form.
4. Place your break points in the XXXfactories/factory methods/XXXtypeFactoryComponentSelectors and make a full debug cycle with several requests.

Have a nice debugging session :)